# How display controls in jwplayer at smartphone same desktop

Tags: android, installation, controls, jwplayer

I've tried config display videos at my website using jwplayer

```
    jwplayer('viewplayer').setup({
    sources: [{
        file: "/video1.mp4",
        type: "mp4",
        label: "360p",
        default: true
    }],
    tracks: [ {
        file: "/video1.srt",
        label: "English",
        kind: "captions"
    }, ],
    width: "100%",
    image: "/img/poster/video1.jpg",
    title: "video1 my webiste",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    primary: "html5",
    modes: [{
        type: "html5"
    }, {
        type: "flash",
        src: "/templates/js/jwplayer.flash.swf"
    }, ],
    skin: {
        name: "seven",
        background: "transparent",
    },
    controlbar: "none",
    autostart: false,
    captions: {
        color: "#FFFF00",
        fontSize: 15,
        backgroundOpacity: 30
    },
});
```

- controls smartphone : play, HD button controls desktop : play, HD,
  CC, volume button and progress bar

[Display controls at smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB4oa.png)

[Display controls at desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCqAU.png)

Please help me about how display controls at smartphone as same as desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a answer for my question. Because i didn't understand this source code, other member modified it.

This css don't display controls at smartphone

```
.jw-reset {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100%!important;
}
#viewplayer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px
}
```